# Can a text block inside an image block have a hover setting than can affect the image block?

Tags: css

I'm working with an object in WordPress, a block with a picture background and a white border, and a text block inside it that doesn't fill the full picture space, like it has padding, but there is no padding being used. The background of the object has an overlay transparency setting that I have at 50%. The customer asked me to have a hover make the opacity change to 20% and to lose the white border. I was able to do that with the class of the "uagfb-section__overlay" class.

The text block is smaller in the center of that div, in the next div "uagfb-section__inner-wrap" and when you hover over that, the opacity of the photo goes back to 50%. If the cursor is outside that text div, but inside the overlay div, the opacity is at 20%. Is there a way to have the overlay class maintain an opacity change regardless of the hover over the text block which is in the center?

I have looked at other CSS selectors like `>`, `+`, and `~` but they don't relate to what I need. It seems it would be nice if there was a selector that affected a parent based on a child's behavior like a `<` but that doesn't exist.

The HTML...

```
 <div class="wp-block-column">
    <section class="wp-block-uagb-section uagb-section__wrap uagb-section__background-image uagb-block-1695edec-a8de-49d4-8758-1ac29736dab0 cause-section-block">
<div class="uagb-section__overlay"></div>
<div class="uagb-section__inner-wrap">
    <p style="color:#ffffff" class="has-text-color has-text-align-center has-regular-font-size">Promoting Wellness</p>
    </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

My CSS to trigger the opacity change...

```
.cause-section-block .uagb-section__overlay:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the css property :

```
pointer-events: none;
```

in the **uagb-section__inner-wrap** css class could do the job.

More info on : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: That's IT! It works. THANK YOU for taking the time to share that with me. Very valuable help, Heya.